# Help I'm trapped in an infinite loop and I can't get out

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-computercraft

Like a complete genius, I put this in the `startup` program:

```
while true do
  shell.run("power")
end
```

Which seemed fine at the time, except now I need to edit something. Here's the fun part: when I try to terminate the program, it will terminate `power`, and then immediately restart it. The turtle has a label, so breaking him will not work, and I'm on a SMP server, so I don't have access to the files. Help?

Comment: *golfclap*...well done.

Comment: ...my only option is finding someone with access to the serverside files, isn't it...?

Comment: Or consigning this one to a lava pool and building another.

Comment: What you need to do is...What you need to do is...What you need to do is...What you need to do is...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put it next to a diskdrive with a disk which has a do-nothing `startup` (ensure the drive is not on a side with a peripheral). Computers prefer to boot from disk over local files unless otherwise specified in the config.

Answer (score 1):

Open the computers UI, press control-T and hold it (for a second if I recall correctly). This will terminate the current program and return to the command prompt. (Another one to remember is control-R, used in the same way, to restart the computer.)

Comment: I did this, and it did not work simply because of the way that I had the loop set up. I would terminate the interior program, but the loop in startup immediately restarted the program.

Comment: Although unrelated to the actual solution, this helped me escape from a sleep loop I was trapped in, so thanks!